# JQuery change color based of class based on HTML content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use JQuery to get the inner html of a div (class box_bottom).

These div's are javascript generated, pulling from XML, therefore (dependant on the XML) there could be (and so I need to cater for) multiple occurrences, so cannot do this by ID. If the content is "notifications" then I want the color to be blue, and if the content is "VO" I want the color to be red

```
 $.category = $('.box_bottom').innerHTML;
    if ($.category == 'Notifications') {
     $(".box_bottom").css("color", "blue");
     }
     if ($.category == 'VO')
     {
     $(".box_bottom").css("color", "red");
     }
```

Chrome dev console is not showing any errors - I am unsure where I am going wrong.

Complete novice to JQuery so have just been googling syntax - so apologies if this is a super simple issue.

Comment: console.log($.category) or alert($.category) to chck whther $.category contains a value

Comment: Hint: Sometimes is it more helpful to create a live example on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: undefined - there is content in the class "box_bottom" - am I doing something wrong declaring the variable / getting innerHTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access `innerHTML` property on jQuery object. You need to use `html()` instead of `innerHTML`

*Change*

```
$.category = $('.box_bottom').innerHTML;
```

*To*

```
$.category = $('.box_bottom').html();
```

*OR*

```
$.category = $('.box_bottom').text();
```

You may also need to use $.trim to avoid any extra space within text, and its better to use category instead of $.category as it defined category with `$` jQuery object.

```
$.category = $.trim($('.box_bottom').text());
```

Comment: This has sorted it! Thank you, need to get my Syntax sorted for both JS/JQuery

Answer (score 1):

```
 $.category = $('.box_bottom').text().trim();
 if ($.category == 'Notifications') {
   $(".box_bottom").css("color", "blue");
 }
 if ($.category == 'VO')
 {
   $(".box_bottom").css("color", "red");
 }
```